# rails 2.3 convert hash into mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to find out how rails converts a hash **such as** (This is an example please do not take this literally I threw something together to get the concept by I know this query is the same as User.find(1)):

```
{
    :select => "users.*",
    :conditions => "users.id = 1",
    :order => "username"
}
```

Into:
    SELECT users.* FROM users where users.id = 1 ORDER BY username

The closest thing I can find is ActiveRecord::Base#find_every

```
 def find_every(options)
   begin
     case from = options[:from]
     when Symbol
       instantiate_collection(get(from, options[:params]))
     when String
       path = "#{from}#{query_string(options[:params])}"
       instantiate_collection(format.decode(connection.get(path, headers).body) || [])
     else
       prefix_options, query_options = split_options(options[:params])
       path = collection_path(prefix_options, query_options)
       instantiate_collection( (format.decode(connection.get(path, headers).body) || []), prefix_options )
     end
   rescue ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound
     # Swallowing ResourceNotFound exceptions and return nil - as per
     # ActiveRecord.
     nil
   end
 end
```

I'm unsure as to how to modify this to just return what the raw mysql statement would be.

Comment: Why do you want to use a hash here? Your query would be just `User.find(1)` in Rails. Btw. using a order when the result would be one specific item makes no sense.

Comment: That is true however it doesn't cover the issue I have.  I'm using paginate and I've recently had to use the HAVING keyword.  Unfortunately my grouped results are specified in the select which is destroyed by will_paginate.  However if I can get the above to work, I can call paginate_by_sql which will wrap the query and return the correct counted result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few hours of digging I came up with an answer although its not great.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self._get_finder_options options
    _get_construct_finder_sql(options)
  end

  private
  def self._get_construct_finder_sql(options)
    return (construct_finder_sql(options).inspect)
  end
end
```

adding this as an extension gives you a publicly accessible method `_get_finder_options` which returns the raw sql statement.

In my case this is for a complex query to be wrapped as so

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM (INSERT_QUERY) as count_table
```

So that I could still use this with the will_paginate gem.  This has only been tested in my current project so if you are trying to replicate please keep that in mind.